# Converting 3x32x32 size numpy image array to 32x32x3 and saving to actual image in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-processing, reshape

I have an image in a numpy array of shape (3072,1) or (3,32,32). This consists of first 1024 values corresponds to **Red component** followed by 1024 **Green component** followed by 1024 **Blue component**. These 1024 values corresponds to 32x32 size image. I want to know is there any pythonic way or shortcut to convert this array to 32x32x3 size array so that I can save the array to actual image?

The problem here is if I just **reshape** it with size(32x32x3) by

```
x = numpy.reshape(x,(32,32,3))
```

then the pixel values will be jumbled up and I won't get the actual image after saving since the original image was of shape (3,32,32)

I just want to save the array into actual image.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [transposition](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html):

```
x = numpy.transpose(x, (1, 2, 0))
```

This means that, denoting the original axes order as `0, 1, 2`, you want them to be rearranged in the order `1, 2, 0` — that is, move the first axis (color values) to the right.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`np.rollaxis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.rollaxis.html) :

```
In [5]: np.rollaxis(a,0,3).shape
Out[5]: (32, 32, 3)
```